# How can I read log file?

Tags: python, logging, logfile

I am learning logging in python. However, I can't find the log file anywhere. Below an example code

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.basicConfig(filename='my_app.log', filemode='w', format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
logging.debug('This will get logged')

file = open('my_app.log', 'r')
```

Unfortunately, the result is.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'my_app.log'
```

I am quite puzzled. What is wrong?

Thanks to Felix, I found a solution. Combining the two `logging.basicConfig` lines helped. The working code looks like this:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='my_app.log',
                    filemode='w',
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('This will get logged')
```

Apparently the later `logging.basicConfig` command will be ignored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your code as follows:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename="my_app.log",
                                    filemode='a',
                                    format='%(asctime)s,%(msecs)d %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
                                    datefmt='%H:%M:%S',
                                    level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('This will get logged')

file = open('my_app.log', 'r')
```

The issue seems like you were setting `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)` before `logging.basicConfig(filename='my_app.log', filemode='w', format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')` Instead you could combine them as:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename="my_app.log",
                                    filemode='a',
                                    format='%(asctime)s,%(msecs)d %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
                                    datefmt='%H:%M:%S',
                                    level=logging.DEBUG)
```